# How to set white space under figure to specific figure?

Tags: graphics, floats, captions, lengths

I don't want to do this in the preamble to set it for all figures. I want to have this for one specific image / figure.

Is this possible? If so, how can I do this?

```
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{2ex} % White space under figures
```

I have this, but this is for all images. I want it for one specific figure...

Comment: Just a hunch: If you put `\vspace*{\glueexpr 2ex - \belowcaptionskip}` after the caption, does that do it? (I'd try it myself, but am too lazy to cook up a MWE to experiment with.)

Comment: Try inserting this command just before the figure, and put the whole in a group?

Comment: I suppose you could put the `\setlength` command *inside* the `figure` environment. That already provides grouping, so it remains local. Why didn't I think of that? (Thanks, @Bernard.)

Comment: if you just want to affect space in one place it is possible to locally change the parameter, but it is simper and more natural just to insert space at that point with `\vspace{2ex}` or whatever space you want.

Comment: Re my first comment: I suppose `\belowcaptionskip` is not a rubber length, so `\dimexpr` may be more appropriate than `\glueexpr`. But presumably, the latter will work wherever the former one does.

Comment: I fixed it by using \vspace! Ah, marvelous. Thank you all!

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen: I thought of it, but I wondered whether it wasn't too late, and I didn't have time to test. Actually, you're certainly right, because I remember having used `\captionsetup{...}`  inside the environment.